# Why this script works only if I use Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, lazy-loading

I'm facing a tedious problem with a js script I written to lazy load the images on a webpage.

This script works in Firefox, Opera and Edge, but in Chrome works only if I toggle the device toolbar, even when the viewport is set on 4K. When the device toolbar is inactive the script won't works and the various high res images are not downloaded.

Script:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var lazyImages = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img.lazy"));
let active = false;

console.log("IntersectionObserver" in window);

if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
  let lazyImageObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach(function(entry) {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        let lazyImage = entry.target;
        lazyImage.src = lazyImage.dataset.src;
        lazyImage.srcset = lazyImage.dataset.srcset;
        lazyImage.classList.remove("lazy");
        lazyImageObserver.unobserve(lazyImage);
      }
    });
  });

  lazyImages.forEach(function(lazyImage) {
    lazyImageObserver.observe(lazyImage);
  });
} else {
  const lazyLoad = function() {
    if (active === false) {
        active = true;

        setTimeout(function() {
            lazyImages.forEach(function(lazyImage) {
                if ((lazyImage.getBoundingClientRect().top <= window.innerHeight && lazyImage.getBoundingClientRect().bottom >= 0) && getComputedStyle(lazyImage).display !== "none") {
                    lazyImage.src = lazyImage.dataset.src;
                    lazyImage.srcset = lazyImage.dataset.srcset;
                    lazyImage.classList.remove("lazy");

                    lazyImages = lazyImages.filter( function (image) { return image !== lazyImage });

                    if (lazyImages.length === 0) {
                        document.removeEventListener("scroll", lazyLoad);
                        window.removeEventListener("resize", lazyLoad);
                        window.removeEventListener("orientationchange", lazyLoad);
                    }
                }
            });

            active = false;
        }, 200);
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener("scroll", lazyLoad);
  window.addEventListener("resize", lazyLoad);
  window.addEventListener("orientationchange", lazyLoad);
}
```

});

Markup:

```
<img class="lazy" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/drp9iwjqz/image/upload/e_blur:2000,f_auto,q_auto:eco/v1509298941/jeremywagner.me/about/st-paul-1x.jpg" data-src="https://res.cloudinary.com/drp9iwjqz/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto/v1509298941/jeremywagner.me/about/st-paul-2x.jpg" data-srcset="https://res.cloudinary.com/drp9iwjqz/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto/v1509298941/jeremywagner.me/about/st-paul-2x.jpg 2x, https://res.cloudinary.com/drp9iwjqz/image/upload/f_auto,q_auto/v1509298941/jeremywagner.me/about/st-paul-1x.jpg 1x" width="400" height="267" alt="A city skyline.">
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure about it, but I worry about the line where you use the `getBoundingClientRect()` method. It seems it has some [issues](https://caniuse.com/#feat=getboundingclientrect) in Chrome. I can't see the CSS, so I don't know if it is your case.

Comment: Hi @amedina, thanks for reply. That block of code it doesn't be executed, because the `"IntersectionObserver" in window` return true in Chrome